# How to profile Windows explorer.exe

Tags: windows, profiling

What tool / technique would you recommend for Explorer.exe profiling?

Mainly on Windows XP / x86...

To avoid confusion it is not a system kind of question.
Imagine, you have developed a BHO or another shell extension and you have to profile it.

For now, I'm using [AMD CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/cpu/CodeAnalyst/Pages/default.aspx), but I'm looking for somethign better suiting for purpose.

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Vista, XPerf is what Microsoft uses to test app perf.

Comment: Windows Performance Analysis Developer Center
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This belongs in serverfault.com, yes?

Try Process Explorer:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx